# How can I track which software/process stops the windows firewall?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, event-log, trojan

Something stops the windows firewall.
If I restart it, it is again stopped within 2 minutes.

**How can I track which software/process stops it?**

Or how to configure the event manager in order to track what is stopping the firewall?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the events here:

Application and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Windows Firewall With Advanced Security

Here you can check who and what has disabled your firewall, in my case I did it myself just to test. It should look something like this, you can see that Value = No. That means firewall is turned off.

[image: Firewall off]

Comment: Thanks a lot:

The application is this one `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netsh.exe`

Is it that some script is launching it? I have now to track what is launching netsh, no?

Comment: And modifying user is the System `S-1-5-18` which is not the current user `S-1-5-21-4001752...`

Comment: Are you on a home network or in a work/domain network? If you're in a work network I would advise you to call your IT-Administrator immediately and let him know that someone or something is messing with your firewall. If you are on your home network I would advise you to give us some more information. Which antivirus you use etc.

Comment: Computer is on the home network, with various Windows and Linux machines on this network.
The only protection is the Windows Defender.

Comment: A scan searching for `advfirewall` only found a `gatherNetworkInfo.vbs` script and `AuthFWSnapIn` and `MIGUIControls.resources` DLLs. No other scripts or executable

Comment: The faulty action seems to be something with the same effect as the command `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\netsh.exe advfirewall set allprofiles state off`. 

Is it possible to track it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I installed an anti-virus "Avira" and launched a scan several times. First it found the Trojan "TR/Crypt.XPACK.e5637e" in various files:

```
C:\WINDOWS\urzivdfs.exe 
C:\WINDOWS\jupkeyptbl.exe
C:\WINDOWS\urzivdfs.exe
```

Second the "TR/BitCoinMiner.fopp" in

```
C:\Windows\p2p_05\win32\win32blot2.exe
```

Now everything is fine: the firewall remains ON.

Thanks **Bungicasse**, your help led me to the conclusion that something stopped maliciously the firewall using the command netsh.

Thanks again,

Alex